# Magento user roles question?

Tags: magento

I am learning through the Magento theme customization and Module creation steps, i have a question about user roles in Magento

- If i have multiple stores in my website, will the admin of one store can access details of another store. And is there any super admin like user role who can view all the stores products?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The backend for magento is one so different users with different privilege can enter the same backend for all store...

you can also limit access of user to different features and configurations. Like you can give one user the privilege to see orders and another one to approve invoices.

Plus you can define the scope so that one user can enter certain store values.

The default admin have access to all store all features.

Comment: so to create roles as like i wanted.. i need to create users and allocate privileges to them?

Comment: Magento does fully support ACLs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).  Create a group assign privileges and then assign users to the different groups.

Comment: Magento eav defines it as Rule (for resources) > Role (group) > user